# ASP.NET Could not load type 'System.String'

Tags: asp.net, string

Has anyone ever seen an issue with an ASP.NET websuite blows up on initial login, complaining about a system.string type in the profile that is defined in the web.config.

More Info:

```
Server Error in '/abc' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Attempting to load this property's type resulted in the following error: Could not load type 'System.String'.

Source Error: 


Line 222:           </providers>
Line 223:           <properties>
Line 224:               <add name="FirstName" type="System.String"/>
Line 225:               <add name="LastName" type="System.String"/>
Line 226:               <add name="DriverCode" type="System.String"/>


Source File: d:\Inetpub\wwwroot\abc\web.config    Line: 224 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.1433; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.1433
```

Answer (score 3):

I haven't seen that, but the docs say that System.String is the default, so try just removing the type part.

Comment: John,  thanks for the idea.  This application has been deployed a couple of dozen times w/o issue.  I did go ahead and try what you said, but it still blows up on the System.Boolean property.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like something in the deployment is badly hosed then. Have any service packs been applied, or anything else that would affect the ASP.NET installation?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this Q&A: [Using a profile property of type List in .NET Membership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199395/using-a-profile-property-of-type-list-in-net-membership)

Try to add a fully qualified assembly name, like:
`<add name="MyString" type="System.string, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>`

That made it work for me.

Comment: One way to get the fully qualified assembly name is to run AssemblyQualifiedName on the type, like this: System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection sc = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();
Console.WriteLine(sc.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName);